# flutter app gradle Daemon is stuck , how to solve it?

Tags: flutter, gradle, daemon

I want to run my Flutter app for the first time on emulator . at first I had problem to running it at gradle . then I deleted the gradle folder and download it manuall and replace it in the folder . gradle version is 8.0-all , its fine here . but the Daemon part is problem . it stuck at :

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[+1136215 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +22 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
[        ] > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
```

and more ...

and If disable it with this code at gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

doesnt work too .

is there anyway to setup Daemon separately? or any other solution

please give me a hint . Im stuck at this running for days . thanks

Comment: generate new project  with flutter and try compile android project. then compare gradle version used for building new project.

Comment: thanks . i created a new project and the gradle version was 7.4 but didnt run like the main project . then I downloaded this version and put it in the gradle folder and run the main project . still the same problem . flutter doctor shows no errors . im so confused

Comment: it's hard to say what problem . it's down to experience in native android development. so  assume your experience here is quite limited. you need consider have live chat with android  native developer  to be able resolve this problem

Comment: thank you . i have a question , can we share the gradle folder ? mine ii not working . maybe if I could use another person gradle folder will be workable?

Comment: generate new flutter project. in the new flutter project navigate to android project. then inside android project copy gradle folder into your android project. . it should solve your problem. validate that no problem  execute command  flutter run android inside your flutter project